# Adding two arrays together

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I call two feeds that both return an NSMutableArray, I then need to make the two arrays into one.

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [JSONWrapper downloadFeed];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [JSONWrapper downloadFeed];

// something like: array1 += array2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`-addObjectsFromArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBD):

```
[array1 addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSArray *newArray = [array1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

Comment: This is the message you would send if neither array were mutable, or if you did not want to mutate either array.