# Objective-C adding values of 2 arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have NSArray1 = (1, 5, 2)
and NSArray2 = (1, 3, 5)

i want to array1 + array2 = (should return) = (2, 8, 7)

(in fact is it even possible to do this with NSArray)?

Heres a similar question 
[Adding two arrays together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835205/adding-two-arrays-together)
(but this adds the values of the second array onto the end of the first array)

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1" ,@"2",@"3",nil];
NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1" ,@"2",@"3",nil];
NSMutableArray *c = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
c = [a addObjectsFromArray:b];
```

// just a test code . . . .

Comment: If you really want to use code similar to what you've written in your sample, you would need to create a *category* on NSArray and implement the new array creation in a `addObjectsFromArray` method there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a C array, then just do

```
int newArray[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    newArray[i] = array1[i]+array2[i];
```

But if it's a NSArray with NSNumbers (You can't have primitives in NSArray), then just do

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0;i<[array1 count];i++)
    [newArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[array1 objectAtIndex:i] intValue]+[[array2 objectAtIndex:i] intValue]]];
    //If you're using Mountain Lion, then you can use the following 
    //[newArray addObject:@([array1[i] intValue]+[array2[i] intValue])];
```

**Edit:**

If you have more than 1 array, then

```
int numArrays = 3;
NSArray *arrayOfNum = //An array of arrays that contains all the numbers
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array]
for (int i=0;i<[array1 count];i++)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int x=0;x<numArrays;x++)
        total+=[arrayOfNum[x] intValue];
    [newArray addObject:@(total)];
}
```

Comment: To clarify `addObject` places values at the end value of the array, which works but nonetheless if you have more then one array to add it does not work

consider using `replaceObjectAtIndex` if adding more then 1 array or when iterating through multiple Arrays.

Comment: What...?  If you have more than one array you can just do `[newArray addObject:@([array1[i] intValue]+[array2[i] intValue]+[array3[i] intvalue])`.  Or if you have an unknown amount of arrays to add, you can create another loop, which I'll add some sample code to my question.